# How to display the number of all checkboxes that have been checked in Table, asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View like below

```
 <input type="checkbox"  />

 <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th> Selected  </th>
          <th>  Name </th>    
      </tr>      
      <tr> 
          <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelitem => item.IsChecked, new {})  </td> //only to count this checkbox
          <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Name) </td>  
      </tr>         
 </table>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-count-checked-checkboxes" name="count-checked-checkboxes" readonly="readonly" />

 <script>
      var $checkboxes = $(' input[type="checkbox"]');
        $checkboxes.change(function () {

            var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
            $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
        });
 </script>
```

The script works well to calculate the number of checkboxes that have been checked. But what I want is only to count the number of checkboxes that have been checked on the table list.
How to do that. Please Help :)

Comment: Can you clarify please? What you mean checked on table list? May be $('.table  input[type="checkbox"]')

Comment: I mean, in that view there are two checkboxes, one outside the table, and one inside the table. the script that I made to calculate all the checkboxes that have been checked. but I want to calculate the checkbox checked in the table.

Comment: Use my code above. You need to more specify the selector. Just add class .table before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate elements with `data-` attributes to distinguish them from the rest and to group them. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

In your example, the checkboxes that you want to count can be given an attribute `data-count-group="insidetable"`.

In MVC this can be done this way:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelitem => item.IsChecked, new { data_count_group = "insidetable" })
```

Using jQuery you can then detect changes to all the checkboxes with that attribute and count all the checked ones:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[data-count-group]', function(e) {
    // get the group
    var group = $(this).data('count-group');

    // get the count for group
    var checkedCount = $('input[data-count-group="'+group+'"]:checked').length;

    // display the count
    $('span[data-count-total="'+group+'"]').text(checkedCount);
});
```

Here's a working example with multiple groups of checkboxes: https://jsfiddle.net/xd80a6r9/3/